# why iterator variable initialization is done inside for each block in java

Tags: java, loops, foreach

I am new to java and I am working with arrays and for each loop.I am facing a problem with iterator initialization.

Code works fine when iterator variable initialization is done within for each block while code throws error when iterator initialization is done outside the loop

For example:

This code works:

```
 class Array {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
            for (int iterator : array) {
                System.out.println(iterator);
            }
        }
    }
```

This code does not work

```
class Array {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
        int iterator;
        for (iterator : array) {
            System.out.println(iterator);
        }
    }
}
```

Someone please give me some insight about the topic and also if someone can explain about the memory mapping of for each loop it will be usefull. Thanks in advance

Comment: your look should look like: `for (int iterator : array) {` and remove the above `int iterator;`

Comment: @kism3t I understand that the syntax for "for-each " loop is for(int iterator : array). But why is my question.

Comment: If you do, I do not understand why you are so supersized that the code does not work. The code you provided will not compile.

Comment: It doesn't 'work' because it is *invalid syntax*. No other explanation needed.

Comment: It's unconventional and confusing to name a variable `iterator` when it doesn't point to an `Iterator`.

Answer (score 3):

It's just how the [enhanced `for` loop is defined](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2). The variable that receives each value *must* be declared in the loop header.

The reason is that a *separate* variable is created for each loop iteration. In the linked spec section, see the example of what the enhanced `for` loop would look like if it were a simple `for` loop:

```
// Your enhanced `for` loop rendered as a normal `for` loop per the spec:
int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
{
    int[] a = array;
    for (int index = 0; index < a.length; index++) {
        int iterator = a[index];
        System.out.println(iterator);
    }
}
```

Notice how `iterator` (not a great name for that variable) is *recreated* on each iteration. (It's conceptually similar for the other form of enhanced `for` dealing with an `Iterable` instead of an array.)

One advantage of it being a separate variable every time is that we can use `final` with it, which is useful particularly if we want to use its value in a lambda.

That also addresses your question about memory: As with any block, new stack space is allocated and used for the locals within the block. We have three levels of that in the above: The freestanding block wrapping the entire thing containing the notional `a` variable; the `for` statement itself containing `index`; and the body block containing `iterator`.

---

It's worth noting that the enhanced `for` *could* have been defined such that it let you *optionally* declare the value variable outside the loop, it just wasn't. It could have been defined such that if the variable were pre-declared, inside the loop iteration it would just do an assignment, not create a new variable and do an assignment. But it would have made it more complicated, and it already had the complication of needing to handle both arrays and `Iterable`s. Apparently the cost of the complication wasn't considered worth the flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

You are braking the syntax of enhanced loop. A compilable for each loop syntax is

```
EnhancedForStatement:
for ( {VariableModifier} **UnannType** VariableDeclaratorId : Expression ) Statement
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2

Loop must know in it's type in it's  own scope, since you breaking that, the error.